# Double values are missing . in mssql

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

I'm converting string to double, everything seems ok until I check the value in MSSQL DB.
If HallTwoTempMin has value 24.9, in database it is saved like 249. How can I fix this problem?

```
HallTwoTempMin = Convert.ToDouble(hallTwoFinalPartMin);
```

Model Sensor:

```
public class Sensor
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public double HallOneTempCurrent { get; set; }

    public double HallOneTempMin { get; set; }

    public double HallOneTempMax { get; set; }
}
```

MSSQL Data Type: float

[image: img]

Thank you in advance.

Update:
Instead of double I change the type to decimal, partially solved my problem. Because when I run the console application locally I will get 24.90 (example) value, but when I publish the application on server and run it the value is 249.00 (I test this multiple times)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i1ynE.png)

Comment: What is the string value of `hallTwoFinalPartMin` in the first snippet? And what is your Locale?

Comment: And I'd strongly suggest to _not_ use `Convert.ToDouble` but one of the `double.Parse` or even `double.TryParse` overloads.

Comment: *"MSSQL Data Type: float"* As a side note, is `float` really the correct data type choice as well? It is *very* rare that a base 2 data type is the correct choice for numbers like the ones you show.

Comment: the string value is "&nbsp;28.6". I do substring -> "28.6" and last convert.ToDouble. I don't think that is the issue, since with breakpoint I can see it has double value right before the data is inserted into DB. Im might missing dataannotation maybe

Comment: It would help if the question showed how this information was being put into the database, as there are a multitude of ways this can be done; and there might be something about the way it's being done which relates to the problem.

Comment: Is the standard for your Locale to use a decimal *comma*? Then it would ignore a dot as "just a grouping character". You may need to specify an InvariantCulture